# I need a way to store the last 0xFFF bytes written to a stream in some kind of buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a decompression routine in Node.JS using streams but I need to save the last 0xFFF bytes written to the stream in a temporary buffer.

I have some code that would work but it just seems inefficient, is there any equivalent to this with the Node.js [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object?

```
var arr = Array(0xFFF) // allocate an array to use as a buffer

function writeByte(byte, stream){
  arr.shift() // remove the first byte in the buffer
  arr.push(byte) // push the new byte onto the end

  stream.write([byte]) // send the byte to the stream
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

Comment: Maybe a ring buffer that is the length of the content you want? This way when the stream ends the buffer will have the amount of data you want and won't store the entire stream?

Comment: Is a ring buffer what I'm looking for? I know what I need, but not what it's called.

I currently allocate the entire decompressed data in a Buffer object and currently, for example, use buffer[buffer.length-1] to get the last byte written.

The byte that I need could be anywhere in the buffer, that's just an example.

Comment: Your questions said the last 4095 bytes of a stream. How are you determining what bytes you need?

Comment: based on a number of variables, I calculate a displacement from the end of the buffer to write to the output

https://gist.github.com/DanTheMan827/ebe98abcbc448aae0127faf1928d436a

Comment: The maximum that the disp value can be is 0xFFF, hence the need for a buffer to store that many bytes that have been written